# Root equation - What am I missing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

There's a problem of which I know the solution but not the solving process:

> $(\sqrt{x} + 7)(\sqrt{x} - 1) = \frac{105}{4}$

I'm convinced that up to:

> $x + 6\sqrt{x} - 7 = \frac{105}{4}$

everything is correct.

But afterwards, I never seem to be able to get to the solution of $x = \frac{49}{4}$

How can this equation be solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Your equation can be rewritten as
$$
(\sqrt{x})^2 + 6 \sqrt{x} -\frac{133}{4} = 0
$$
And so it is a quadratic equation in $\sqrt{x}$ that you can solve. So you find that $\sqrt{x}$ is equal to some number(s).

Comment: Are you sure that $-\frac{77}{4}$ is correct?

Comment: @MiroslavCetojevic oops, you are right. I edited the answer...

Comment: I got $-\frac{133}{4}$, but otherwise it looks like this was the hint I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @MiroslavCetojevic, again: you are right. I am not good with numbers :) Glad that it helped though.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ Put $\:z = \sqrt{x},\:$ clear denominators and rearrange to obtain the quadratic equation$\:0 = 4 z^2 + 24 z - 133 = (2z-7)(2z+19),\:$ solvable by the quadratic formula, or the [Rational Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) or  [AC method,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/138949/242) etc.

Alternatively, purely arithmetically, if it has rational root $\:\sqrt{x} = a/b\:$ in lowest terms then

$$ (\sqrt{x} +7)(\sqrt{x}-1)\ =\ \frac{a+7b}b\ \frac{a-b}{b}\ =\ \frac{3\cdot 5\cdot 7}4 $$

Since $\:b\:$ is coprime to $\:a,\:$ also $\:b\:$ is coprime to $\:a+7b,\ a-b,\:$ so we deduce  $\:b = 2.\:$  Hence

$$  (a + 14)\:(a-2)\ =\ 3\cdot 5\cdot 7 $$

So we seek a factorization of $\:3\cdot 5\cdot 7\:$ whose factors differ by $\:16 = a+14-(a-2).\:$ Checking the few possible factorizations we find $\:21\cdot 5\:\Rightarrow\:a=7,\:$ and $\:-5\:(-21)\:\Rightarrow\:a = -19.\:$ Notice that this solution depends on *uniqueness of factorization* (as does RRT and the AC method).

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion:

1. Multiply the given equation by $4$ to have integer coefficients only. (You may omit this step)
2. Expand the LHS.
   $$4x+24\sqrt{x}-28=105.$$
3. Isolate the term with a square root on one side.
   $$24\sqrt{x}=133-4x.$$
4. *Square both sides* (*this may introduce a new solution*) and simplify. You get a quadratic equation. One of its two solutions satisfies the original equation. $$x_1=\frac{49}{4}.$$