# How to solve $(\sqrt{x}+7)(\sqrt{x}-1)=\frac{105}{4}$?

Tags: roots, quadratics, factoring

I'm having difficulties solving $(\sqrt{x}+7)(\sqrt{x}-1)=\frac{105}{4}$. I guess I'm missing a crucial point. The solution is $x=\frac{49}{4}$. What are the steps?

Comment: Put $t=\sqrt{x}$ and then solve the second degree equation in $t$

Comment: For your convenience, let: $t=\sqrt{(x)}, t\ge 0$, then factor out and solve a quadratic equation with variable $t$, if any $t \ge 0$ then you can find $x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root equation - What am I missing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145498/root-equation-what-am-i-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the user Dark Magician said, we can use the substitution $t=\sqrt{x}$. We get the following from using the quadratic formula:

\begin{align}
(t+7)(t-1)&=\frac{105}{4}\\
t^2-t+7t-7&=\frac{105}{4}\\
t^2+6t-7-\frac{105}{4}&=0\\
t^2+6t-\frac{133}{4}&=0\\
4t^2+24t-133&=0\\
t&=\frac{-24\pm\sqrt{24^2-4\times4\times(-133)}}{2\times4}\\
t&=\frac{-24\pm\sqrt{576+2128}}{8}\\
t&=\frac{-24\pm\sqrt{2704}}{8}\\
t&=-3\pm\frac{13}{2}\\
t&=-\frac{19}{2}\ or\ \frac{7}{2}
\end{align}

We know that $t$ is nonnegative, as it is an arithmetic square root, so

$$t=\frac{7}{2}$$
$$x=t^2=\frac{49}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining in great detail! I tried substitution before, not quite sure what I missed, maybe some addition or division error...

Comment: No problem! It is just that the answers for $t$ are not integers, so you couldn't have factorised $133$ easily. The quadratic formula is my preference for most equations that have at least degree 2 that cannot be factored into integer solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $t = \sqrt x$.

Then we can convert the question to

$(t + 7)(t - 1) = \frac{105}{4}$

Simplify it to get the following quadratic in $t$

$4t^2 + 24t - 133 = 0$

There are many ways to solve a quadratic.

By any method, you will get the following solutions for $t$

$t_1 = \frac{7}{2}$

$t_2 = \frac{-19}{2}$

From here, we can solve for $x $ to get the desired answer. Note that we want $t$ to be positive therefore we do not consider $t_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The question setter has the intention of requiring a "$t = \sqrt x + 3$" substitution such that the original becomes $(t + 4) (t - 4) = 105/14$.

Then, $t^2 - 4^2 = 105/4$

.......