# What is the mathematical proof behind the shortcut used in this video, Factoring Trinomials with Leading Coefficient not 1 (fast way)?

Tags: factoring

My teacher found this cool shortcut for factoring. I would like to use, for it saves time, but I feel hesitant using it without knowing the mathematical proof. Can anyone watch the video and explain it to me, thanks. The link to the video is here, http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=r1JAJfmRG5w.

Comment: The answer by Gone in this question may be what you are looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138925/factoring-ac-to-factor-ax2bxc?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with any quadratic with integer coefficients:
$$Ax^2+Bx+C$$

Now let's follow what your teacher did.

Step 1. Write $x^2+Bx+AC$.

Step 2.  Factor $x^2+Bx+AC=(x-q)(x-p)$.

Step 3.  Write $(x-\frac{q}{A})(x-\frac{p}{A})$ and reduce the fractions $\frac{q}{A}=\frac{r}{s}$ and $\frac{p}{A}=\frac{t}{k}$.

Step 4.  The desired factorizations is $(sx-r)(kx-t)$.

To prove this works, note from step 2 that 
$B=-(q+p)$ and $AC = pq$.  This is sufficient information to obtain the  roots of $Ax^2+Bx+C$ by the quadratic formula:
$$ x=\frac{-B\pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}= \frac{q+p\pm \sqrt{(p+q)^2-4pq}}{2A}= 
\frac{q+p\pm \sqrt{(q-p)^2}}{2A}.$$  So the roots are $\frac{q}{A}$ and $\frac{p}{A}$. This agrees with what we found above, since $\frac{q}{A}=\frac{r}{s}$ and $\frac{p}{A}=\frac{t}{k}$.